# Lista encadeada, união de estruturas

Tags: c, struct, lista-encadeada

Estou com certa dificuldade em unir duas estruturas numa mesma lista encadeada, nunca trabalhei com listas genéricas ou mesmo associei numa atividade duas estruturas, tenho as seguintes estruturas:

```
struct Patio {
    char iden_patio;
    int capacidade;
    struct Patio *prox;
};  

typedef struct Patio patio;

struct Rec_Emp {    
    char nome_rec[10];
    char ident_rec[10];
    int uso_rec;
    int taxa_rec;
    struct Rec_Emp *prox;
};    

typedef struct Rec_Emp recuperadora;
```

Queria associar essas duas listas sem necessariamente unir todas as variáveis, mais ou menos assim, para cada pátio, associar os elementos das recuperadoras, ex: iden_patio: A, capacidade: 10000, nome_rec: Rec01, uso_rec: 0, etc... Como disse poderia até unir as duas, formar uma struct maior, porém gostaria de uma solução mais elegante, pois queria preservar as identidades dos patios e das recuperadoras, agradeço atenção desde já.

Comment: Como exatamente você queria associar essas estruturas? Qual a finalidade da associação?

Comment: Não perder a identidade das estruturas, no EP que estou fazendo, a cada pátio está associado uma ou mais recuperadoras (o ep é sobre a logística de um porto), assim preservando as estruturas, as duas separadas, seria uma solução mais elegante e mais clara pro quem entrar em contato com o código (o professor, p. ex.), e até pra mim. Fiz a união das estruturas, achei muito bagunçado

Comment: Bom, eu posso te dar uma resposta completa. Entretanto eu preciso de mais algumas informações: Existe um limite de recuperadoras para um pátio? Você pretende fazer essa associação para saber quais recuperadoras estão associadas à um pátio ou, qual pátio está associado a tal recuperadora?

Comment: Para cada patio associo até duas recuperadoras, então o pátio B teria as recuperadoras Rec01 e Rec02, o pátio A, teria só teria somente a recuperadora Rec01, mas o caso de A, seria o único com apenas uma recuperadora, todos os outros pátios terá duas recuperadoras.

Comment: me ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412245/lista-encadeada-socorro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com as informações que eu tenho sobre o seu problema já consigo te entregar duas respostas.

**Levando em conta que você precisa saber quais recuperadoras estão associadas a um pátio, recomendo fazer assim:**

```
#define RECS_PATIO 2

struct Rec_Emp {
    char nome_rec[10];
    char ident_rec[10];
    int uso_rec;
    int taxa_rec;
    struct Rec_Emp *prox;
};

typedef struct Rec_Emp recuperadora;

struct Patio {
    char iden_patio;
    int capacidade;
    struct Patio *prox;
    struct Rec_Emp *lista[RECS_PATIO];
}; 

typedef struct Patio patio;
```

Usando as estruturas acima, vamos supor que você queira associar uma recuperadora r a um pátio p e depois imprimir algum valor da recuperadora acessando pelo pátio. Faz assim:

```
p.lista[0] = &r;
int resp = 0;
resp = p.lista[0]->uso_rec; // Acessando uso_rec da recuperadora pela variável do pátio
```

**Levando em conta que você precisa saber qual pátio está associado a uma recuperadora, recomendo fazer assim:**

```
struct Patio {
    char iden_patio;
    int capacidade;
    struct Patio *prox;
}; 

typedef struct Patio patio;

struct Rec_Emp {
    char nome_rec[10];
    char ident_rec[10];
    int uso_rec;
    int taxa_rec;
    struct Rec_Emp *prox;
    struct Patio *p;
};

typedef struct Rec_Emp recuperadora;
```

Usando o código acima, vamos supor que você queira associar um pátio p a uma recuperadora r e depois imprimir algum valor do pátio acessando pela recuperadora. Faz assim:

```
r.p = &p;
int resp = 0;
resp = r.p->capacidade;
```

Espero que tenha sanado suas dúvidas, qualquer coisa estou a disposição.

Referência: Meus conhecimentos em AED's.

Comment: Essa estrutura que me passou acredito que entendi, mas agora surgiu outra questão que não tinha me deparado, até consegui inserir os valores das estrutura individualmente, nesse caso subi de um arquivo .txt, porem não consegui associar a cada pátio as informações das recuperadoras. (falo especificamente do primeiro exemplo, com " struct Rec_Emp *lista[RECS_PATIO];"

Comment: A constante RECS_PATIO significa recuperadoras por pátio. Cada pátio tera uma lista de recuperadoras de tamanho RECS_PATIO. Entendido isso, se você quer associar uma recuperadora a um pátio, apenas inclua a recuperadora na lista do pátio desejado. Fazendo isso você vai ter associado ao pátio, todas as informações da recuperadora. Caso não seja essa sua dúvida, me fale para eu poder abrir uma sala de bate papo. La nos podemos conversar sobre isso a vontade.

Comment: Certo. Na função inserir estou subindo os dados de um arquivo .txt, tenho no arquivo tenho, p. ex., “ 600000 B REC01 REC03 0 0 6000 8000 “, que são respectivamente, capacidade, identificação do pátio (esses dois na estrutura pátio), recuperadora 1 e 2, uso 1 e 2, taxa de recuperação 1 e 2 (esses associados a estrutura recuperadora), tô batendo cabeça no seguinte, qdo insiro no arquivo, devo primeiro fazer um pra cada estrutura? ou posso inserir direto, tipo: novo.lista[0]->taxa_rec = tx_recup1, novo.lista[1]->taxa_rec = tx_recup2.

Comment: Não posso te chamar no chat, agora, pois estou no trabalho, mas se ainda estiver com dúvida, posso te chamar a noite? Obs: na estrutura recuperadora, exclui a variáriável char ident_rec[10];, pois como esse novo formato ela perde sentido.

Comment: Claro, aguardo o chat para podermos discutir melhor!

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/56331/associacao-de-lista-encadeada?tab=general

Comment: Entrei no chat e postei minhas questões, mas tu não apareceu rsrs

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56334/discussion-between-carlos-givisiez-and-marcelo-de-sousa).

Comment: Carlos, pode ir ao chat?

Comment: Perdão pela demora, respondi o que me perguntou no chat